# Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file Return code is: 401

Tags: android, maven, authentication, android-gradle-plugin, sonatype

I am trying to upload my library, [ListBuddies](https://github.com/jpardogo/ListBuddies), to maven. To do that I am using the [gradle-mvn-push](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push) github project of @ChrisBanes . I follow all the steps that he mentioned on his repo plus some others that are needed before that repo is used:

- I opened a [Jira](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) issue and I waited until It got resolved
- I have created [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) keys
- I configurate [ListBuddies's build.gradle files](https://github.com/jpardogo/ListBuddies) and the [gradle.properties](https://github.com/jpardogo/ListBuddies/blob/master/gradle.properties)
- I have created another local gradle.properties at "/Users/jpardogo/.gradle/gradle.properties"

local gradle.properties file (signing keys are only need for release so should not be a problem for the SNAPSHOT):

```
//These are the username/password that I use for:
//[JIRA](https://issues.sonatype.org) 
//and [NEXUS](https://oss.sonatype.org

NEXUS_USERNAME=jpardogo1
NEXUS_PASSWORD=jira-pass

//This is the key ID that I obtain doing "gpg --list-keys" on the terminal
signing.keyId=my-keyid

//This is the paraphrase I set when I first created the key
signing.password=my-paraphrase

//That's the path to my secret key ring
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/jpardogo/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Look like everything is setup properly but when I do:

```
gradle clean build uploadArchives
```

At the end I receive code ERROR 401:

```
:library:uploadArchives                 
Uploading: com/jpardogo/listbuddies/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-20140209.151716-    1.aar to repository remote at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
Transferring 67K from remote            
:library:uploadArchives FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':library:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Error deploying artifact 'com.jpardogo.listbuddies:library:aar': Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file:     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jpardogo/listbuddies/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-20140209.151716-1.aar. Return code is: 401

* Try:         
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I have been looking for an answer the whole day of yesterday and today as well but I couldn't solve it. The error 401 reason is good explain in [here](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/24431007-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Deployment-Failures), but I couldn't solved anything and I also read that It could be due user permissions problem although I register on Jira as the [guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) says.

I hope you can help me with that and If you need any more information, please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT: I want to update the question with the link to the [jira ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-8676) and its comments.

Comment: Have you tried to login into Sonatype Nexus via your credentials ? The credentials for JIRA and for Nexus are usually not the same....May be in your case they are, but first i would try to login via Browser...

Comment: Yes I did, I login with these credentials (username and password) on Nexus UI at https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#welcome

Comment: Have you added `authentication(userName: mavenUser, password: mavenPassword)` in your build.gradle file?

Comment: The whole project is publish on github (http://goo.gl/SiD5LR), it is open source. It is working with gradle-mvn-push and the authentication line is on here http://goo.gl/iuk8dx . gradle-mvn-push readme explains its functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it. All the configuration was ok. The problem was on the file `gradle.properties`. Because I copy  paste the structure of the file, a hidden tabulation reminded next to the NEXUS_USERNAME, so the username actually was being sent with the tabulation and I was receiving a authentication error.

Sometimes things are more simple than you think, and you don't see them. The first thing I will do the next time will be to check the format of the files.

Comment: Yes, it is awesome solution. i have tried for a month's )).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and the **reason** was: my password (generated) contained a backslash `\`.

**Solution**: Backslashes need to be escaped in `gradle.properties`!

**Example**:

```
ossrhPassword=partBeforeBackslash\\\\partAfterBackslash
```

instead of:

```
ossrhPassword=partBeforeBackslash\partAfterBackslash
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was uploading a version that already exists in the rep. The solution was just to change the 'version' in the build.gradle file.